# Can you negate search for extended properties in Event.list of google calendar api?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve all events which do not have a specific sharedExtendedProperty with the [Events.list API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list).

Some of my events have the sharedExtendedProperty `test` and I was wondering if I can get all events which **do not** have this property at all. (I dont care about the value, just the key)

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/extended-properties) you can AND and OR different properties but it sais nothing about negating them.

I tried `!propertyName=test`but this did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does not accept `not` filtering, if you want to do this you have to retrieve all and filter locally.

Answer (score 0):

A quick experiment showed that it seems to work with
`propertyName!=value`

In our case we filter out events we created through private extended properties.

`is<Company>Event!=true` and we always create the events with the value `true`.